# Angular 4: Couldn't send value to web api using post

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, angular4-httpclient

I am using asp.net core web api and angular4.

In my app.module.cs

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
imports: [
    HttpClientModule
]
```

In my service

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

 obj = {
"ID":"null",
"Name":"John",
"Cgpa":"3.90"
}
constructor(http: HttpClient) {

http.post(
    'http://localhost:33969/api/home/Save', 
    JSON.stringify(this.obj),
    headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json')
   .subscribe(
    res => {
      alert("Student Saved!");
      console.log(res);
    },
    err => {
      alert("Error!");
    }
  );
}
```

In my web api,

```
public Student Save(Student s)
{
    //Saving code goes here
}
```

In my student model,

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Cgpa { get; set; }
}
```

I put a debugger point on the API's action. But couldn't receive any value from client side. But i tried with postman and it works.
[image: Here is sent a dummy object and it did insert in database]

May be i am missing something from client side

Comment: Can you remove JSON.stringify() and try?

Comment: I tried without json.stringify in the first place. Later i added this. Also another thing to note: Using postman, it only works when i send as form-data. But when i send with raw json. Then couldn't receive the value. I think its the api that has  problem